# Sharepoint 2013 - Script to Allow Sharing Site or library only to administrators

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharing, powershell-script

I'd like to disable sharing to all members except administators on ALL Site Collections.
Is there a Powershell command that match my request ?

Or maybe only admistrators will approve sharing request.

Thank you for your help

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to disable sharing for non-owners by using PowerShell in the SharePoint server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Emily.
Meanwhile, I found this checkbox where we can disable sharing :
https://t684v1bpeth2fnqjg2ecece5-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Access-GMT-000007.png

But why don't I have this Check box on my site :
https://i.postimg.cc/FR3V9rV8/2020-12-14-14h20-30.png

Thank you

Comment: The checkbox "Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders." is not available in the SharePoint server. It is only available in the SharePoint Online.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and have a nice day !